# bash: string concatenation inside a parameter of a command

Tags: string, bash

I would like to run a command in a bash script according to the following code sample. Despite the fact that j and i variables contain the filenames (these filenames were read out from the samples.list.txt), these strings can't be inserted into the command. What could be wrong? Many thanks!

```
cat work/sample.list.txt | while read line;
do
    arrIN=(${line// / })
    i=${arrIN[0]}
    j=${arrIN[1]}
    k=${arrIN[2]}

   java -jar some.jar ./input1directory/"$i" ./input2directory/"$j" 
done
```

Comment: What's you `sample.list.txt` contents?

Comment: currently only one line

Comment: control_0_D10_1.fq control_0_D10_2.fq control_0_D10

Comment: What's the point of replacing space with space? Why not just `arrIn=($line)`?

Comment: @szusz Your script looks working, what do you mean by "these strings can't be inserted into the command"? What output do you get?

Comment: @Samuel: I get the following: java -jar some.jar ./input1directory/ ./input2directory/ instead of this:  java -jar some.jar ./input1directory/control_0_D10_1.fq ./input2directory/control_0_D10_2.fq

Comment: Strange... your script working for me. Please run following `printf "%d" "'$IFS"` and post here the output

Comment: it looks strange for me, but this is what I got: 32bcbio@ubuntu:~/simulation$

Comment: Well, your default delimiter is ok. Please run your script as follows: `bash -x ./yourscript.sh` and post here the output. Thanks

Comment: @Samuel: now it seems correct, I think it's more like a Java input  stream related problem, because I still got the java.io.FileNotOFoundException... and these files certainly exist in the right place. any way, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can read multiple variables at once, like this:

```
while read i j k ; do
   java -jar some.jar ./input1directory/"$i" ./input2directory/"$j" 
done < "work/sample.list.txt"
```

Every line `read` reads will get subject of word splitting and the individual fields will get assigned to the variables you specify on the command line. If there are more fields than variables, the whole remaining line gets assigned to that last variable specified.